# rollup.JS and "'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, angular, rollupjs

I'm trying to bundle Angular2 modules using Rollup.js.
this is my rollup.config.vendor.js file:

```
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';

export default {
    entry: 'vendor.ts',
    dest: './Bundle/vendor.js',
    format: 'iife',
    moduleName: 'vendor',
    plugins: [
        typescript(),
        resolve({
            jsnext: true,
            main: true,
            browser: true
        }),
        commonjs({
            include: 'node_modules/rxjs/**',
        }),
    ]
}
```

It creates a bundled js, but in the process it keeps printing this kind of message:

```
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#this-is-undefined
node_modules\@angular\forms\@angular\forms.es5.js (1:25)
1: var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
                            ^
2:     for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
3:     function __() { this.constructor = d; }
```

What does it mean?
Am I doing something wrong or is it the way it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could safely ignore those warnings as explained in the [`documentation`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#rollup) by adding the `onwarn` property to your `rollup-config.js` file:

```
onwarn: function(warning, handler) {
    // Skip certain warnings

    // should intercept ... but doesn't in some rollup versions
    if ( warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED' ) { return; }

    // console.warn everything else
    handler( warning );
}
```

Quote:

> It overrides the default onwarn method in order to skip annoying messages about the AOT compiler's use of the this keyword.

Comment: In my case I can't ignore these warnings because it actually breaks the bundle.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the `context` option and set it to `this`: it avoids the rewrite of `this` to `undefined` (in fact `this` is rewritten to... `this`).

See Rollup documentation:

- https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-this-is-undefined
- https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#context

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is that `typescript` will attempt to shim out `await` if the language target is too low, and `typescript`'s await shim leans on global this.  The warning is triggered by the use of global this, which it can't prove was safely stubbed out (but was.)

Whereas you can cause the error message to be omitted, since you're bundling, the better choice is to use a language target that presumes await.

In your `tsconfig.json`, set `target` to `es2017` or higher, and this will go away. The value of the `lib` property must also be properly defined. i.e.:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "ES2017",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "lib": [                                             /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
      "ES2017",
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable"
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: seems did not work for me. I set the target to es2017 but still did not fixed.

Comment: set also lib:
```json
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable"
    ],
```